# Topology induced by smooth structure of a Riemannian manifold $M$ "compatible" with the norm; neighbourhood basis of $(p,0)\in TU$

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold. My question is related to [Application of theorem 2.2. to Geodesic Flow - Chapter 3, Do Carmo Riemannian Geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3288659/776794). Lee Mosher states that the sets

$$\mathcal{U}(\epsilon_1) = \left\{ (q,v) \in TU ; q \in V\ \ \text{and}\ \ v \in T_q M \text{  with  } \;\; |v| < \epsilon_1 \right\},\quad \epsilon_1 > 0,$$

form a neighbourhood basis of $(0,p)\in TU$. It follows that every neighbourhood of $(0,p)$ in $TU$ contains such a set $\mathcal{U}(\epsilon_1) $ for some $\epsilon_1>0$, which answers the question.

However it isn't clear to me why these sets define a neighbourhood basis. As described in Remark 2.3 on page 3 of Riemannian Geometry by do Carmo, the topology of $TM$ (or any manifold) can and, in do Carmo, is usually defined by the differential structure of $TM$ which, in my mind, doesn't have to be "compatible" with the norm induced by the Riemannian metric (in the sense that we can always find $\mathcal{U}(\epsilon_1)$ in any given neighbourhood). On the other hand, I don't have much experience with topology, so I'm probably wrong.

Comment: Since you only care about them being a neighborhood basis, you can assume $U$ to be the domain of a chart, which induces a trivialization $TU\cong U\times\mathbb{R}^n$, which you can refine to be a fiber-wise isometry by Gram-Schmidt. This reduces the question to sets of the form $V\times B_{\epsilon}(0)$ where $V$ is a nbhd of $p$ in $U$ and $B_{\epsilon}(0)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is the $\epsilon$-ball around the origin (wrt the Euclidean metric) forming a neighborhood basis of $(p,0)\in U\times\mathbb{R}^n$, which is clear.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why can we assume that $U$ is the domain of a chart? I also don't understand why the isometry allows us to translate the problem to sets $V\times B_{\epsilon}(0)$. Could you maybe go into a little more detail?

Comment: Cause every point has a chart neighborhood and describing a neighborhood basis is fundamentally a local issue. The sets $V\times B_{\varepsilon}(0)$ correspond to the set $\mathcal{U}(\epsilon)$ (though I don't like this notation as it leaves the $V$ implicit) as you have written it under a fiber-wise isometric trivialization, which is in particular a homeomorphism.

Comment: Thank you! One last question: I understand that the neighbourhood basis is a local problem and we can always describe a manifold $M$ by a chart in the neighbourhood of a point of $M$. When you assume that $U$ is the domain of a chart, are you using the fact that every chart is a diffeomorphism and thus a homeomorphism, so we can deal with open sets in the domain instead? Or am I missing the point?

Comment: the topology of $TM$ is locally the same as the standard topology of an Euclidean space, and any norm in an Euclidean space defines this topology